# String matching techniques

Tags: ruby, regex, string, string-matching

The following strings are considered equal. How can I match stuff like this?

```
"Hazard Const. Company"
"hazard construction company"

"PETERSON-CHASE GENERAL ENGINEERING CONSTRUCTION INC"
"peterson-chase general  engineering construction inc"

"TRAFFIC DEVELOPMENT SERVICES "
"traffic development services"
```

My environment is ruby, but I'm just wondering general principles to match strings. The above examples don't work w/ rudimentary "a"=="b" because of whitespace issues, and abbreviations. I can mitigate casing issues w/ regex case-ignore or downcase the strings...

Comment: Do you have a complete set of abbreviations? If you did, you could expand all the abbreviations and normalize whitespace and case.

Comment: Nope, don't know the abbreviations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following sample compares all of your strings and computes the levensthtein difference (amount of keystrokes it takes to adapt one string to the other).

Based on a defined maximum difference and with a compensation for the lengts of the string it then puts the strings in a hash as a key with the number of occurences als value.

```
require 'levenshtein'

MAX_DISTANCE, COMPENSATION = 3, 5

strings = [
    "Hazard Const. Company",
    "hazard construction company",
    "PETERSON-CHASE GENERAL ENGINEERING CONSTRUCTION INC",
    "peterson-chase general  engineering construction inc",
    "TRAFFIC DEVELOPMENT SERVICES ",
    "traffic development services"
]

result = {}
strings.each do |s|
    s.downcase!
  similar = result.keys.select { |key| Levenshtein.distance(key, s) < MAX_DISTANCE+(s.length/COMPENSATION) }
  if similar.any?
    result[similar.first] += 1
  else
    result.merge!({s => 1})
  end
end

puts result.inspect
# {"hazard const. company"=>2, "peterson-chase general engineering construction inc"=>2, "traffic development services "=>2}
```

Comment: Thanks, "Levenshtein" was the word I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

String#squeeze
String#downcase

And for the first one, you'll have to calculate levenshtein distances or similar.

Comment: Thanks, "levenshtein" was the word I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

An interesting question that belongs to the subject of text mining and information retrieval. Usually you can achieve described matching using stemming (lemmatization) algorithms or even through a simpler heuristics.

1.) The latter case would be to process both strings to get the normalized versions of each and then do the comparison. We can replace larger whitespaces with one space and downcase all characters on both strings. Example of string normalization:

```
string.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').downcase
```

This wouldn't work on abbreviations tough.

2.) You can get better results if you use a stemmer to normalize each word token into common base form. Few examples of stemmings: words=>word, feet=>foot, construction=>construct, ... Once you get the word bases (also called lemas), you can join them into a string. And then make a comparison. Usually the stemmer will do the downcase for you so you can skip that step.

So both of those two strings:

```
"Hazard Const. Company"
"hazard construction company"
```

Get converted to:

```
"hazard construct company"
```

The code depends on the actual stemmer used. For example, you can look at this one: https://github.com/aurelian/ruby-stemmer

The actual output of stemmed words will also depend on the stemmer used. The way stemmers (lemmatizers) work is not just through some kind of trimming rules, but they also try to match words to internal library of word bases (lemas). Therefore a good lemmatizer will recognize Const. abbreviation and match it against construct lema.

Since not all abbreviations can be recognized (but for example just 90% of them), it is  better not to match the exact strings. But try calculating their similarity through distance calculation (as @7stud suggested) and tweaking a threshold of acceptable similarity based on the test data results. This is the usual approach in information retrieval. The more you can customize and specialize your text processing, the better results you will get. And other way around - the more you try to build generic processing, the harder it gets and the results will be worse.